# What is $\mathbb P\{X_2\in B_2, X_1\in B_1\mid X_0\in B_0\}$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I denote $\mathbb P_X(A)=\mathbb P\{X\in A\}$, $\mathbb P_{X,Y}(A\times B)=\mathbb P\{X\in A, Y\in B\}$ and so on...

We have that $$\mathbb P\{X_2\in B_2, X_1\in B_1, X_0\in B_0\}$$
$$=\int_{B_0}\mathbb P_{X_0}(dx_0)\mathbb P\{X_2\in B_2, X_1\in B_1\mid X_0=x_0\},$$

Now, what is $\mathbb P\{X_2\in B_2,X_1\in B_1\mid X_0=x_0\}$ ? I know that $$\mathbb P\{X_2\in B_2, X_1\in B_1\}=\int_{B_1}\mathbb P_{X_1}(dx_1)\mathbb P\{X_2\in B_2\mid X_1=x_1\},$$

but I don't know how to get $$\mathbb P\{X_2\in B_2, X_1\in B_1\mid X_0=x_0\}.$$
I would guess that it's $$\int_{B_1}\mathbb P_{X_1\mid X_0=x_0}(dx_1)\mathbb P\{X_2\in B_2\mid X_0=x_0, X_1=x_1\},$$

But I don't understand how to interpret $\mathbb P_{X_1\mid X_0=x_0}(B_1)$... the notation looks strange for me.

Comment: Could the person who downvote explain ? I think I really explain where my problem is... And sorry if my question is so obvious for the downvoter, but it would be more helpful to answer than to downvote without any explanations

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. But I don't know what we can say about $g(x):=\mathbb P(X_2\in B_2,X_1\in B_1\mid X_0=x)$ except that $g(X_0)$ is a version of $\mathbb E(\mathbf 1_A\mid X_0)$ where $A:=\{\omega \ : \ X_2(\omega)\in B_2, X_1(\omega)\in B_1\}$.